# Unity CanvasRenderer expects meshes with 16 bit indices for drawing a graph chart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When applying `IndexFormat.UInt32` to a **UI Mesh**:

```cs
mesh.indexFormat = IndexFormat.UInt32;
```

Unity complains about the **CanvasRenderer expects meshes with 16 bit indices**, but I have not found how to change it to 32 bit indices.

Does is it possible to apply `IndexFormat.UInt32` to a CanvasRenderer?

**[EDIT 1]**

I'm using Unity `2019.3.0f3`, the issue comes with this package: [assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/graph-and-chart](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/graph-and-chart-78488)

Sometimes a graph chart **can have more 5000+ items**.

Comment: I'm guessing since there is a specific error message about it, the answer is no. You could try and write something yourself

Comment: The error comes with no stacktrace only the message is displayed.

Comment: Why does it matter if it has a stacktrace? Unity's current UI implementation obviously doesn't support it. What version of Unity are you using? Also, why do you need a >65,535 vertices mesh in the UI? Maybe I can think of a workaround

Comment: Yeah used this package in the past ... **don't**! ... it creates thousends really slow UI upates/drawcalls everytime you change something within it ... Rather complain/ask the developer of the tool or try to get a refund ^^ You shouldn't try to fix an asset you didn't create yourself .. especially if you pay for it

Comment: I'm trying to display a graph chart which can have a lot of objects and therefore a lot of vertices

Comment: @derHugo I haven't the choice of using another package unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fix I have filtered my data by using the **Douglas-Peucker Line Approximation Algorithm** which consists in compressing a data curve.

The source code of the implementation can be found here: [A C# Implementation of Douglas-Peucker Line Approximation Algorithm](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18936/A-C-Implementation-of-Douglas-Peucker-Line-Appro)

And an explanation of the algorithm: [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)